# What is best way to get lowest adsorption site at subsurface of high entropy alloys?

Tags: density-functional-theory, surfaces, transition-state

I am currently studying diffusion of oxygen in high entropy alloys. I want to calculate the activation energy from an adsorption site on the surface to the subsurface. I placed the oxygen atom below the adsoprtion site which is the octahedral site. However, the energy there is high and during the transition state calculation there is no transition state even when at the point where the oxygen atom lies on the same plane with the surrounding atoms. Any idea why? For instance the energy I got from one adsorption site is -702.9264 eV whereas that for the final state is -70.6669 eV. I have attached my two POSCARS for the final and initial states.

```
Co Cr Fe Ni  O 
 1.0000000000000000
    10.0453568374981206    0.0000000000000000    0.0550632930546681
     5.0062629241308159    8.6637900144891251   -0.0307447571247709
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   24.5023355004677370
 Co  Cr  Fe  Ni  O  
  24  24  24  24   1
Selective dynamics
Cartesian
  8.7766571015478032  2.1777634888882269  3.1080740310962058   F   F   F
  6.2782974601486963  7.9582629368528934  1.0190222525127322   F   F   F
  0.0274266946359444  0.0055177027200366  3.0657900259957507   F   F   F
  6.2466554474958640  6.5122750488135317  3.0610751658681195   F   F   F
  8.7627181505054867  6.4954382872392689  3.0559812109569062   F   F   F
  8.7953340244117282  7.9490487603472797  1.0418268933671475   F   F   F
  7.5451005419151320  4.3561802749796597  3.1073725012384239   F   F   F
  9.9963484714175461  5.7599382799285257  1.0248594669588107   F   F   F
  8.7618449996810774  7.9520263054541989  7.1596134241032052   T   T   T
 11.3064477104372081  5.0703329320231649  5.1497019503353334   F   F   F
 10.0511573105272269  5.7748678882568454  7.1697534960504150   T   T   T
 11.2734085310770347  3.6249672551060113  7.1877668713499805   T   T   T
  3.7476834024317180  3.6014574163070301  7.1389683868952529   T   T   T
  3.7781274372021176  5.0611187555175512  5.1174432981350799   F   F   F
  2.5071304514035702  1.4764318150220832  7.1861125931300869   T   T   T
  4.9791418842079009  2.8720082750988585  5.1004758717267427   F   F   F
  3.7607282935853994  5.0949972152369014 11.1491506911820490   T   T   T
  6.2637032412862954  2.1577927045694798  9.2340933791758939   T   T   T
  5.0612530356151701  2.9631344192881439 11.1814394828411068   T   T   T
  6.2824969032520324  0.7429695333939030 11.2080620182675830   T   T   T
  8.8079117515256051  0.7077715135484740 11.2096953029187318   T   T   T
  8.8027377709552947  2.1426254744270188  9.2388112581673933   T   T   T
 12.5403333883320354  7.2706927553702636 11.2320447392269678   T   T   T
 15.0317183647889490  8.6456670477059578  9.2260538736180404   T   T   T
 11.2794658606395775  2.1854049478835345  3.0932120682100694   F   F   F
 13.8429752095551102  8.0081264762626798  1.0400778428739901   F   F   F
  7.5062089299346431  8.5878716931148436  3.0404139188623431   F   F   F
 12.5292398688526205  5.7608791135808319  1.0195714317096789   F   F   F
  3.7534020713146861  6.4536868445706039  3.0447474010419744   F   F   F
  2.5074845499179261  1.4383185623716952  0.9638242355764692   F   F   F
  5.0081284709796794  1.4608209784853594  1.0563831099900889   F   F   F
  2.5235105240125639  4.3337415702800852  3.1074366925071208   F   F   F
 11.2753394057028125  7.9640142231110476  7.1361958144732673   T   T   T
  8.8257686223455352  5.1201964714330126  5.1156942476420966   F   F   F
 12.5303024896312998  5.6962032948874235  7.1731262765432815   T   T   T
  7.5120332816430118  2.8729491087511030  5.0951878364777858   F   F   F
  8.7921544303633450  3.5541670778287662  7.1416732646749548   T   T   T
 12.5418977243371810  7.2141785720310914  5.0637591762744725   F   F   F
  4.9971848079008145  7.2366809881447560  5.1012547576334244   F   F   F
  7.5468468348812898  1.4709631772610674  7.2248620684520688   T   T   T
  6.2808566726596400  5.1549512634835093 11.1891940802054126   T   T   T
  3.7463734285110966  2.1246516845159920  9.2749614029934779   T   T   T
  7.5626395776873174  2.8298652491039524 11.1779363858364249   T   T   T
  2.5062690459128030  0.0096842800291125  9.1805761528538934   T   T   T
  3.8259180463606159  0.8267908436997687 11.3286656317032950   T   T   T
  7.5682979533788100  4.2839857617876262  9.1269312920617569   T   T   T
 10.0114962415541395  4.3511678261842279  9.2684139888958281   T   T   T
  7.5859861209357415  7.3537074181087663 11.2142595400918204   T   T   T
 10.0406252428086056  1.4472919183804158  1.0674819665042066   F   F   F
 11.3049315964151855  3.6464452716285356  1.0584426828238245   F   F   F
  8.7550358565393758  3.6106197356729708  1.0709064491924392   F   F   F
  5.0047281251439433  5.8014588244091989  1.0209867053723687   F   F   F
  7.5159956958965415  5.8066510105756048  1.0716763870576809   F   F   F
  3.7753407655435969  2.1787215956348089  3.0762459979654637   F   F   F
 11.2809851393373037  7.9239790621965849  1.0192839404782317   F   F   F
  5.0419904075874920  0.0137745162262661  3.1010962680446039   F   F   F
 10.0296815797298109  7.2231519280398118  5.1123536141473682   F   F   F
  6.2877250092055403  0.7585152667988683  5.1340590875919307   F   F   F
  3.7378292693297657  0.7226897308432422  5.1465228539603718   F   F   F
 10.0328783754324178  2.9135288195795317  5.1516664031951427   F   F   F
  2.4987891086868603  2.9187210057458759  5.1472927918257874   F   F   F
 13.8168186709168825  7.9547738992259029  7.1809487928177962   T   T   T
  6.2637785521277296  5.0360490573669168  5.0949003452461641   F   F   F
  5.0249961691997100  5.7974875217503516  7.1351778608606820   T   T   T
  5.0010580599329444  4.3069351927087940  9.1929993533366261   T   T   T
  6.2381400345651086  6.5096275667068131  9.1490472602378592   T   T   T
 13.7603953379574921  6.4997177622675544  9.2488745421537804   T   T   T
  5.0061008917847136 -0.0405665788476749  9.2687762210429483   T   T   T
  7.5209526452954254  0.0135497355976428  9.2779554155466126   T   T   T
  8.8432559097071533  5.0345783768965866 11.2706443732926722   T   T   T
  1.1956241321445653  2.1740616454687771  9.1729715140630894   T   T   T
 10.0692963663634778  2.9322267687232602 11.2810345422087330   T   T   T
 10.0282735591555721  4.3313931011396187  3.0966945143646889   F   F   F
 12.5607705214336711  8.6554883663487683  3.0613928719889794   F   F   F
  3.7531885525237656  3.6095669801864636  1.0250397720413951   F   F   F
  6.2843209735050918  3.6352415095431208  1.0204056651444602   F   F   F
 11.2691736907421127  6.4832975521152001  3.0644499773991170   F   F   F
  7.5188534806834388  1.4504259056420330  1.0487077995602649   F   F   F
  6.2782788872936743  2.1792855168806664  3.0766347582234115   F   F   F
  5.0232445698807879  4.3284615772184960  3.0649526006409338   F   F   F
  5.0012158211532700  1.4383089216905578  7.1954478625571410   T   T   T
  7.5427289617555919  5.7674533795585239  7.1328962667227405   T   T   T
  8.7813388028122059  0.7216369753567347  5.1557194698639952   F   F   F
  1.2671143862954106  0.7473115047133917  5.0960220699125696   F   F   F
  6.2395768375206382  3.5979160293878061  7.1433841997020755   T   T   T
  7.5079098176046806  7.2262859153014913  5.0935794472036005   F   F   F
  6.2801534394740539  7.9602965800223657  7.1154174001515447   T   T   T
 10.0512121014684084  1.4271148814043031  7.1826088380046693   T   T   T
  4.9929242115854562  7.2729952850677018 11.1806939600262734   T   T   T
  2.5128414752636816  2.9354901309880823 11.2094640783118340   T   T   T
  8.7608688054105155  6.4775809584725836  9.2036818804327059   T   T   T
 11.2980342574920414  6.5059655884210574  9.2029019351776693   T   T   T
  1.2368289301785180  0.7845572632911523 11.2011363102469144   T   T   T
  2.5005222559759464  4.3099569855235016  9.1731022573488659   T   T   T
 11.3223354780756420  5.0955173787297143 11.2366696572531044   T   T   T
 10.0674340246517637  7.2083504689075379 11.2229886021829124   T   T   T
  3.7944115999999997  3.6970970850000002 12.6795779050000004   T   T   T

Co Cr Fe Ni  O                          
   1.00000000000000     
    10.0453568374981206    0.0000000000000000    0.0550632930546681
     5.0062629241308159    8.6637900144891251   -0.0307447571247709
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   24.5023355004677370
   Co   Cr   Fe   Ni   O 
    24    24    24    24     1
Selective dynamics
Direct
  0.7484317155209226  0.2513638356015306  0.1254815499620392   F   F   F
  0.1672130297685186  0.9185659998157476  0.0423655957612539   F   F   F
  0.0024128917846937  0.0006368693967431  0.1251177360037659   F   F   F
  0.2472404547354330  0.7516658457698711  0.1253174855948984   F   F   F
  0.4986791697954516  0.7497224974724048  0.1245421004755940   F   F   F
  0.4183102184453631  0.9175024725961123  0.0427306917694636   F   F   F
  0.5005233982563055  0.5028030766782763  0.1263255330535529   F   F   F
  0.6637932465713661  0.6648289340226086  0.0411694970457788   F   F   F
  0.4143713546072955  0.9195791270995757  0.2928291818442215   T   T   T
  0.8338796964351900  0.5852326664824119  0.2090322624279182   F   F   F
  0.6681726940226745  0.6678054758290204  0.2920397892188706   T   T   T
  0.9129347185456124  0.4186508639296721  0.2915681993845613   T   T   T
  0.1652011482937884  0.4173058804770774  0.2919216603845722   T   T   T
  0.0849768851120345  0.5841691392627766  0.2093973584361279   F   F   F
  0.1647646905545194  0.1726627101023813  0.2941280424147318   T   T   T
  0.3304599132380304  0.3314956006892800  0.2078361637124431   F   F   F
  0.0641867234661763  0.6112182331099643  0.4592078679556754   T   T   T
  0.5032588682500664  0.2477149731787730  0.3762331996710914   T   T   T
  0.3758894523640607  0.3202031080077988  0.4666179688915571   T   T   T
  0.5905184207366735  0.0794506652163967  0.4574070019706649   T   T   T
  0.8369830821968760  0.0804181527923322  0.4552092214207244   T   T   T
  0.7533849423083415  0.2475864316030281  0.3746528958355664   T   T   T
  0.8300822113024559  0.8386557992441651  0.4577131350863883   T   T   T
  0.9991204813157205  0.9972565966857718  0.3749863348390313   T   T   T
  0.9971429636928946  0.2522458351632153  0.1243171831461751   F   F   F
  0.9173969055062088  0.9243213954712743  0.0415462838229530   F   F   F
  0.2532328618483248  0.9912372851549591  0.1247613899134663   F   F   F
  0.9158846146946971  0.6649375277963188  0.0403872990614644   F   F   F
  0.0024110322067799  0.7449034237646117  0.1251928215763556   F   F   F
  0.1668800967370530  0.1660149380313101  0.0391693010992924   F   F   F
  0.4145209940205419  0.1686122327575248  0.0423935979957335   F   F   F
  0.0019224850701747  0.5002131357099415  0.1274453925201016   F   F   F
  0.6621412419298159  0.9205326511378933  0.2912165732773430   T   T   T
  0.5840635721728802  0.5909880621379457  0.2082129504896244   F   F   F
  0.9184242336252958  0.6596921806797450  0.2910468236116485   T   T   T
  0.5825512813613685  0.3316041944629831  0.2070539657281358   F   F   F
  0.6704398697357125  0.4113252093721251  0.2906566016186762   T   T   T
  0.8335467634037173  0.8326816046979744  0.2058359677659638   F   F   F
  0.0811876606872062  0.8352788994241891  0.2090602646624049   F   F   F
  0.6666537515752613  0.1706657800328314  0.2932247753576477   T   T   T
  0.3337144300670556  0.5958147364828910  0.4607377303442761   T   T   T
  0.2512373019453277  0.2481176297797994  0.3795791040313221   T   T   T
  0.5985608829957711  0.3248981831374521  0.4545887832829719   T   T   T
  0.2477401147660520  0.0020811078309796  0.3744314599065798   T   T   T
  0.3364411186108296  0.0836748462121832  0.4652326628750894   T   T   T
  0.5061534199905999  0.4966940220100596  0.3725297049243901   T   T   T
  0.7451397400428083  0.5027312649621911  0.3775297050028986   T   T   T
  0.3318851171962112  0.8470779104591801  0.4588269257678476   T   T   T
  0.9162766261883135  0.1670506690443787  0.0417170310293500   F   F   F
  0.9156348408059642  0.4208833853925711  0.0416680593854295   F   F   F
  0.6638573836196215  0.4167482971811012  0.0427373586771225   F   F   F
  0.1644966505612686  0.6696213567857683  0.0421395064179180   F   F   F
  0.4141908497179116  0.6702206541091940  0.0436478982229787   F   F   F
  0.2505031653515672  0.2514744230863357  0.1253016876192419   F   F   F
  0.6671950880963564  0.9146088546634559  0.0412477173410366   F   F   F
  0.5011301297450359  0.0015898949770516  0.1254391147214591   F   F   F
  0.5829432928549849  0.8337173357110430  0.2083836976960143   F   F   F
  0.5823015074726285  0.0875500520592425  0.2083347260521009   F   F   F
  0.3305240502862929  0.0834149638477655  0.2094040253437868   F   F   F
  0.8311633172279329  0.3362880234524397  0.2088061730845894   F   F   F
  0.0808575163845759  0.3368873207758583  0.2103145648896501   F   F   F
  0.9168886402263001  0.9191816037543051  0.2913564255230319   T   T   T
  0.3338617547630278  0.5812755213301273  0.2079143840077009   F   F   F
  0.1670153395213179  0.6701985324697202  0.2914723656248875   T   T   T
  0.2513060877236921  0.5059887887480221  0.3756358854049534   T   T   T
  0.2475041336434062  0.7518710463757668  0.3743069499944034   T   T   T
  0.9944709779634716  0.7534683990773307  0.3754503470925685   T   T   T
  0.4963786010181460  0.0008845883322630  0.3782850017127863   T   T   T
  0.7483938663396408  0.0023140322445166  0.3760172373135887   T   T   T
  0.5886841789493205  0.5813358099232653  0.4592101505080777   T   T   T
  0.9932347194658880  0.2492186464723799  0.3745183866716416   T   T   T
  0.8283230691797615  0.3385380722410083  0.4592855378745594   T   T   T
  0.7491453254479623  0.4999420685284264  0.1253274286111932   F   F   F
  0.7525172797094726  0.9990417994750018  0.1245053594957000   F   F   F
  0.1659916469114435  0.4166267850617231  0.0419841126835294   F   F   F
  0.4164851590236438  0.4195902143823460  0.0412357760750623   F   F   F
  0.7488913776000459  0.7483211782917962  0.1243236794642684   F   F   F
  0.6650578055559109  0.1674124030264323  0.0415158212312434   F   F   F
  0.4996344114965225  0.2515395125269748  0.1247577710853136   F   F   F
  0.2510709289178692  0.4996037034576872  0.1251508454354209   F   F   F
  0.4139564407648514  0.1683785821615087  0.2936907275540203   T   T   T
  0.4192966940803240  0.6665067325999134  0.2913288929676756   T   T   T
  0.8326583135781078  0.0832934517283874  0.2086507793501937   F   F   F
  0.0831518256903081  0.0862568810490103  0.2079024427417338   F   F   F
  0.4142771789447031  0.4159838270578033  0.2914864395200165   T   T   T
  0.3317244722225823  0.8340790696931037  0.2081824878979148   F   F   F
  0.1674658319402113  0.9194780083071055  0.2913291858935960   T   T   T
  0.9186101039540117  0.1650441399360110  0.2908492879715232   T   T   T
  0.0789380280568836  0.8401892689874880  0.4570481479841009   T   T   T
  0.0637406570088894  0.3280311276366524  0.4616525072358368   T   T   T
  0.4992590235015633  0.7499621165359704  0.3757432306318370   T   T   T
  0.7481627113292969  0.7538512765965829  0.3750773488723150   T   T   T
  0.0761719562687376  0.0861958257701179  0.4575145414611073   T   T   T
 -0.0101939275881990  0.5036624097263601  0.3728582540976973   T   T   T
  0.8270329522360970  0.5896211015886338  0.4587134808476083   T   T   T
  0.5870113370845126  0.8325013505290396  0.4581622644250204   T   T   T
  0.1877794975611008  0.4048523460762901  0.4351072193809827   T   T   T
```

Comment: You need to add your POSCAR files as you have mentioned in your quesiton.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez I have added the two POSCARS. I have tried all methods and I am still not getting any activation energy even though that shouldn't be the case.